# Prove that $f(iz)=\overline{f(\bar z)}$ for analytic $f$ satisfies some condition

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ is entire function in $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $$ e^{-a|x-y|}\leq |e^{if(x+iy)}|\leq e^{b|x-y|}$$ for some $a,b>0$ . Then to show that $$f(iz)=\overline{f(\bar z)}$$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$

I think I need to use Schwarz's reflection principle but I am not getting how to use the given condition.

Comment: Hint: where does $f$ send the line $y=x$?

Comment: $|e^{if(x+iy)}|$ is equal to $e^{-\Im(f(x+iy))}$. Don't know if that helps though. Also, are $x, y$ real?

Comment: Ok so for $y=x$ we are getting $f(x+iy)$ is real valued. So is it like applying Schwarz's reflection principle along the line $y=x$

Comment: Please do not delete a question immediately after receiving an answer.  This is rude to the person who took the time to answer your question, and rude to future readers who might benefit from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the given condition implies that $f(z)$ is real-valued on the line $y=x$. It follows that
$$
 f(r(z)) = \overline{f(z)}
$$
where
$$
 z = x+iy \mapsto r(z) = y+ix = i \bar z
$$
is the reflection at the line $y=x$.